# $\cos(nx)=Q_n(\cos(x))$ for polynomial $Q_n$ of degree $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Are there any proofs of this equality online? I'm just looking for something very simply that I can self-verify. My textbook uses the result without a proof, and I want to see what a proof would look like here.

Comment: You can use induction: express $\cos((n+1)x)$ in terms of $\cos nx$ and $\cos x$. Also, look up "Chebyshev polynomials" and "cosine".

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
e^{inx} &= (\cos x + i\sin x)^n 
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk\cos^{n-k}(x) i^k \sin^k (x) 
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k}\cos^{n-2k}(x) i^{2k} \sin^{2k} (x) + 
 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k+1}\cos^{n-2k-1}(x)
 i^{2k+1} \sin^{2k+1} (x) 
\end{align}

Take the real part of both sides and you get
$$
\cos nx =\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k}\cos^{n-2k}(x)
 (-1)^k (1-\cos^2x)^k
$$

The last expression is clearly a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\cos (x)$.

---

Alternative:

as $$
\cos ((n+1)x) + \cos ((n-1)x) = 2\cos (x) \cos (nx)
$$
you can prove it directly using induction.

Comment: Does $\cos(x)\cos(nx)$ reduce to a square or something? I don't see where the polynomial comes in.

Comment: if $P_k$ is the polynomial for $\cos kx$ for $k$ up to $n$, then this proves that $\cos (n+1)x = 2\cos x \cos nx - \cos(n-1)x$. So that $P_{n+1}$ defined by $P_{n+1}(X) = 2XP_n(X) - P_{n-1}(X)$ is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which proof you are looking for.

Your polynomial $Q_n$ is called the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $N$.

Probably the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) will help you out in finding what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\cos((n+1)x) & = \cos(x) \cos(nx) - \sin(x) \sin(nx)\\
& = \cos(x) \cos(nx) + \dfrac{\cos((n+1)x) - \cos((n-1)x)}2
\end{align}
Hence,
$$2 \cos((n+1)x) = 2\cos(x) \cos(nx) + \cos((n+1)x) - \cos((n-1)x)$$
Therefore,
$$\cos((n+1)x) = 2\cos(x) \cos(nx) - \cos((n-1)x)$$
Now use induction to conclude what you want.